# Associate file type with icon fails

Tags: software-installation, themes, icons, file-association

I am trying to create file associations that will show my icon on file types.

I created the file `myapp-xxx.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/myapp-xxx">
        <comment>My app dummy mime</comment>
        <sub-class-of type="application/octet-stream"/>
        <glob pattern="*.xxx"/>
        <generic-icon name="MyApp"/>
    </mime-type>    
</mime-info>
```

I placed `MyApp.png` in `/usr/share/icons/`

I placed `myapp-xxx.xml` in `/usr/share/mime/packages/`

I ran

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

and my files of type xxx are correctly associated with the mimetype - and start with my executable.

But, running

sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/ -f

The icon did not show on my file, and I got error:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.
```

I tried to mimic the way other programs, like libreoffice, create icons...

Created a directory MyApp inside icons, and created a file index.theme listing a few sizes (16, 24, 32, ...) and in a file called mime I added png resized to those sizes.

I rerun the command  above,

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/MyApp -f

gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
```

But no file association either - in fact, I lost the file association that my .desktop created with the application !

How do I add the icon to my file ?

Comment: The answers to the linked question are very thorough, thank you @karel